# WIF and layered security

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, wif

I've been trying to find an answer to my question, and I haven't even seen my question asked, anywhere.

My problem is this, I have a site, where it requires 3 pieces of information to sign in and perform 90% of the functions, Username/Password and answers to security questions. The user will have the ability to "register the device" so the security questions won't get asked. That's not the hardest part (I think), I can modify the ADFS site to do that easily enough, or so a lot of blog posts are saying.

The problem is that, on some parts of the site, we need to require additional security using "out-of-band" questions. We already have all that code to interface with the vendor for that service, but, we are wanting to use ADFS or some other IP/STS to do the actual authentication, this way it's decoupled from the app and other applications can use that same authentication piece as well.

Has anybody ever done anything like this or is it even possible? Everything I've found is showing only authenticating once and using a single STS. I've found one tiny blurb saying you can use the wauth parameter to request the type, but if they fail the authentication of the "enhanced" security, then the STS invalidates the entire token which we don't want. We are also wanting this token to be automatically invalidated after a certain time period.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you like before the

```
SignIn( UsernameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text );
```

in the FormsSignIn page.

So you could call the vendor interface before there.

But you still have to call the sign-in because that's where the token etc. is generated.

Comment: Right, that's where I would put my code to call out to the vendor, that's fine. What I need to figure out is, how do I get my app to get back to that sso page and authenticate a second time, without invalidating the first login.

Comment: The way I do it is to have another page in ADFS, redirect to the page from the login page, authenticate using whatever method, if OK, redirect back and continue as per normal. Or simply add more fields to the login page and call out from there.